# Objective-C Callbacks/Block Pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

What I am trying to do is load a list of people (JSON format) from a remote server, save the file onto disk, and then parse the result and return an `NSArray *` back to the caller.

I have created a `EmployeeDirectoryManager` that has the following:

```
- (NSArray *)loadDirectory:(BOOL)refreshFromServer;
- (void)loadDirectoryFromFile;
- (void)loadDirectoryFromServer;
```

I would like to use a block on the `loadDirectory` method so the caller can be informed when the `loadDirectoryFromServer`, which is using an `AFJSONRequestOperation` which has a `success` block on it.

I need a little direction on how to implement this, or if I am headed down the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use block in your methods as completion handler, firstly you need define new type

`typedef void(^TypeComplitionHandler)(id result)`

Then you can pass block to your method. For example

```
- (void)loadDirectoryFromFileComplitionHandler:(TypeComplitionHandler)complition {
    complition(@"done");
}
```

Comment: Can you define the block inline on the method in the header?

Comment: sure 
`- (void)loadDirectoryFromFileCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id result))completion {
   completion(nil);
}`